# False passing test while uploading a file using attach_file capybara and cucumber

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a passing test while uploading a file using attach_file, yet the file is not uploaded.

Here is the html of the input:

```html
<input qq-button-id="b29ebeff-8171-4ed7-b249-3396cbc9d18a" type="file" name="upload" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
```

And the step definition :

```html
When(/^I upload my cv$/) do
  @file_path = File.expand_path('../../support/fixtures/qualite-web_emploitic.pdf', File.dirname(__FILE__))
  attach_file(:css, "[name=\"upload\"]", @file_path)
end
```

What am I missing? help please :)
I run through documentation without finding an answer to this problem

Cucumber scenario :

```html
@wip
  Scenario: As an offline emploitic user, I would like to apply to a job
    When I visit a job description
    And I click on apply
    When I upload my cv
    # And I send my application
    # Then I should see the message "Votre candidature a bien été transmise au recruteur."

Steps:

When(/^I visit a job description$/) do
  @job_page = JobDescription.new
  @job_page.load(id: @id)
end

When(/^I click on apply$/) do
  click_first_apply_button
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.frame 'modaliframe'
  sleep 3
end

When(/^I upload my cv$/) do
  @file_path = File.expand_path('../../support/fixtures/qualite-web_emploitic.pdf', File.dirname(__FILE__))
  page.execute_script("$('input[name=upload]').css('opacity','1')")
  attach_file('upload', @file_path)
  sleep 20
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for attachfile - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method - it takes a locator and the file to upload.  The locator is a string matching either the id or name of the file input, or the text of an associate label element.  It does not take a random CSS selector.  In your case that means it should be

```
attach_file('upload', @file_path)
```

The strange thing is I would have expected a FileNotFound error with your usage, are you sure that step is actually being called?

Comment: I've tried attach_file('upload', @file_path) already but it doesn't work as I get a FileNotFound error and there is no id in the html of the input.

Comment: I also tried to insert an id with js to test the upload `execute_script("$('input[name=upload]').attr({id: 'cvFileInput'})")` but `attach_file('cvFileInput', @file_path)` didn't work either. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @ManelAdman Post the exact error you get when calling it correctly

Comment: @ManelAdman you don't need an id, the locator will match id OR name

Comment: After adding a wait time, the test passed when calling it with the name argument but the upload didn't happen. Here is an example of a form containing the file field https://www.emploitic.com/inscription

Comment: and yes the step is being called

Comment: @ManelAdman  Are you sure you're using the selenium driver?  I would have expected the selenium driver to raise an error about not finding the file input due to it not actually being visible on the page (opacity: 0) - and if you're not using selenium but are instead using rack-test then it wouldn't upload the file because the upload is fully JS driven.  All the details you have provided are contradictory., unless maybe you've overridden `#attach_file` with your own version of it.

Comment: I am using selenium as capybara default driver `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium`. I set the opacity to 1 with js but the tests still passed without uploading the file `page.execute_script("$('input[name=upload]').css('opacity','‌​1')")` I have not overriden attach_file

Comment: @ManelAdman since the upload is JS driven (asynchronous), how are you waiting for the upload to finish in your test?  Do you have an expectation for content that appears/changes when the upload is finished, etc?

Comment: The upload doesn't even start. I added a wait option http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions%3Aattach_file and a sleep 20 second to check the upload

Comment: @ManelAdman The wait option is the maximum time Capybara waits for the file field to be visible, it has nothing to do with the actual upload.  What you've told me doesn't make sense, that there were no errors yet you were calling attach_file incorrectly, the field wasn't visible but no error was raised, etc.  Maybe you should upgrade your question with your whole test, otherwise I'm out of guesses as to what you're actually doing.

Comment: is it possible to use element.sendKeys for the upload without passing by capybara? On previous selenium projects sendKeys worked fine for the upload for this input

Comment: @ManelAdman Sure, but that's what Capybara ends up calling after checking the file exists and the input is visible so if Capybara isn't raising any errors it's not going to make a difference

Comment: I'm new with capybara and cucumber, and the fields of these forms are custom fields, that are difficult to select. I have described you as accurately as possible the problem i'm facing with the upload field and it's giving me headaches. ..Anyways the sleep 20 do wait for the page to load  for 20 seconds but nothing happens.

Comment: @ManelAdman as I stated, if you post the whole test I may have more understanding, but as of now what you've stated (no errors) doesn't make sense with your shown code, so I'm out of ideas

Comment: @ Thomas I have updated the post with the test scenario and the steps defs .

Comment: @ManelAdman  Ok - so looking through your code and the emploitic  code.  If the test isn't raising any errors then I think it's either a bug in whatever version of selenium-webdriver you're using that isn't generating a change event on the input (which is what triggers the FineUploader instance being used on the page) or (more likely) you've got a JS error in your app that's preventing the behavior from being applied (check the dev console for errors in the browser that opens during your 20 second sleep), or FineUploader is returning an error but you should see a message in the page for that

Comment: It might be bought. Fine uploader is returning a js error in the console that is not preventing the upload. And there might be a bug in selenium webdriver version for ruby as I tried the same scenario using selenium with java and the file has been uploaded normally.

Comment: @ Thomas thanks a lot for your help and happy new year :)